# How do you grep a file and get the next 2 lines with a tab?

Tags: shell, file, text, grep

I could grep the lines containing the pattern "genes" and the next 2 consecutive lines using the following shell command from a text file.

`grep -A 2 '     gene' file`

output:

```
     gene            1..1515
                     /locus_tag="MSMEI_RS00005"
                     /old_locus_tag="MSMEI_0001"
     gene            2109..3302
                     /locus_tag="MSMEI_RS00010"
                     /old_locus_tag="MSMEI_0003"
```

now my aim is to print the consecutive lines with a tab like

```
gene            1..1515           /locus_tag="MSMEI_RS00005"   /old_locus_tag="MSMEI_0003"  
gene            2109..3302        /locus_tag="MSMEI_RS00010"   /old_locus_tag="MSMEI_0003"
```

how do I do this with the same grep command in shell?

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: working with Ubuntu

Comment: if the contents have 4 columns without space in column content as given in sample, try piping the output to `xargs -n4 | column -t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -nEe '/^     gene/{N;N;s/\n */\t/g;p}' file
```

`/     gene/` works on lines matching that pattern, then we read two `N`ext lines, `s`ubstitute newlines and following spaces with tabs, then `p`rint.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `grep` for it, `Awk` can do this manipulation using its `getline()` function to get the next two subsequent lines,

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}/gene/{getline n1; getline n2; print $0, n1,n2}' file
```

(or) if you are bothered with the leading spaces, strip them using `gsub()` function,

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}/gene/{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",$0); getline n1; getline n2; print $0, n1,n2}' file
```